# Catch any fetch call in angular

Tags: angular, browser, fetch

I am using a library that makes a fetch call and I am not being able to get its response. Is there any way to capture all the calls that are made on a web page? I am looking for a solution that can be implemented using angular.

I have tried with angular interceptors but I am not sure if this is what I need to solve it.

Comment: The only way to catch all fetch calls is to use a ServiceWorker

Comment: And how is this works?